# I have some errors about iconbitmap googletrans | Python

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm doing a translation app and it's got the some error.

**here's my code**

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import Image,ImageTk
from googletrans import Translator

root = Tk()
root.title('google translate')
root.geometry("500x630")
root.iconbitmap('logo.ico')

root.mainloop()
```

and it has errors such as

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "google.py", line 8, in <module>
    root.iconbitmap('logo.ico')
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2071, in wm_iconbitmap
    return self.tk.call('wm', 'iconbitmap', self._w, bitmap)
_tkinter.TclError: bitmap "logo.ico" not defined
```

Comment: Check whether logo.ico exists, and properly contains a bitmap

Comment: In your code, does "logo.ico" represent a filename, or are you expecting it to be the name of a predefined bitmap?